# Selecting data from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently at the moment I have managed to join two tables to retrieve the information that is need.
I have now decided to try and retrieve another piece of information from a another table ( users.user_id ) but the query I'm trying to use doesn't seem to work. If someone could help with the query would be great.

Here is my current query that works fine.

```
     "SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review
      FROM films
      INNER JOIN reviewed
      ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id";
```

Here is the query being used to get data from three tables but wont work

```
    "SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review users.name
      FROM films
      OUTER JOIN reviewed, users
      ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id && films.user_id=users.user_id";
```

Database: `film`

Table structure for table `films`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `films` (
   `movie_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `movie_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `actor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `rating` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


 INSERT INTO `films` (`movie_id`, `movie_title`, `actor`, `rating`, `user_id`) VALUES
  (1, 'batman', 'christian bale', 'Excellent', 3),
  (2, 'Bne', 'reee', 'Ok', 3),
  (3, 'Today', 'dd', 'Fair', 3);
```

Table structure for table `reviewed`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reviewed` (
   `review_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `review` mediumtext NOT NULL,
   `movie_id` int(4) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
   KEY `movie_id` (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;



 INSERT INTO `reviewed` (`review_id`, `review`, `movie_id`) VALUES
 (1, 'Wicked film', 1),
 (2, 'gedtg', 2),
 (3, 'dddd', 3);
```

Table structure for table `users`

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;



INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES
 (1, 'ben@talktalk.net', 'password', 'Ben'),
 (2, 'richard@talk.net', '1', 'richard'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review, users.name
  FROM films
  LEFT JOIN reviewed ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id
  LEFT JOIN users ON films.user_id=users.user_id
```

Comment: This error is occurring with that query -: **Could not execute mysqlYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN reviewed ON films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id OUTER JOIN us' at line 3 **

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you want to have the user_id in your reviews table?
That way you'd have the following:

1. table of movies; only one per movie
2. table of users; only one per user
3. table of reviews; one per review linked to a user and to a movie

The reviews table would now have the rating, the review itself, a user id, a movie id and a unique review id.

That way a Batman could be given an Excellent rating by me and an Average rating by you without duplicating the movie row.

To just fix your above query, you can use the following:

```
SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review, users.name FROM films, reviewed, users WHERE films.movie_id = reviewed.movie_id AND films.user_id = users.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print only films with reviews, you don't need OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review users.name
FROM films JOIN reviewed on films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id
JOIN users ON films.user_id=users.user_id;
```

If you want to print all films, even those with 0 reviews, you have to use LEFT JOIN (MySQL doesn't have FULL OUTER JOIN).

```
SELECT films.movie_title, films.rating, films.actor, reviewed.review users.name
FROM films LEFT JOIN reviewed on films.movie_id=reviewed.movie_id
LEFT JOIN users ON films.user_id=users.user_id;
```